# Wordpress Pods shortcode pagination don't work

Tags: wordpress, pagination, archive, shortcode

I've created a pods template for my pods archive and I use a shortcode inside of a new wordpress page for diplaying it. I'de like to display a pagination but when I use `pagination=”true” pagination_type=”advanced”` nothing happend. Can you please tell me what's wrong ?

- Here my shortcode :

  [pods name="seminaire2" orderby="ezdatedebut asc" template="archive_template_seminaire" limit="5" where="t.post_status in('publish')" pagination=”true” pagination_type=”advanced” ]
- My pods template :

```
    <div class="portfolio oceans terres atmosphere" style="display: inline-block;" data-bound="">
        <div class="item_paysage"> 
          <a class="item_link" a href="?p={@ID}">
            <div class="vignette"> 
              [if ezvignette ]
              <img class="img-fluid " src="{@ezvignette._src}" alt="event_img" /> 
                [else]
                <div class="substitute_img fa fa-users"></div>
              [/if]
              
             
                <!--<img class="masque" src="http://wordpress.localhost/wp-content/themes/ipsltheme/ipsl/img/masque_paysage.png" alt="Masque IPSL"> -->
                <img class="masque noprint" src='[masque name="portrait"]' alt="Marque IPSL"> 
            </div>
          </a>
          <figcaption>
            <div class="img_title">{@post_title}</div>
            <div class="propos_img">{@ezdescription} </div>
          </figcaption>
          
          <button class="btn nuance-1"><a href="?p={@ID}"><span class="btn_title">Voir + </span></a></button>
          <!--<button class="btn nuance-1"><a href="#"><i class="fa ipsl_sphere"></i></a><span class="btn_action">Site dédié</span></button>-->
        </div>
      </div>
  <!--FIN PORTFOLIO ITEM-->
```

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your problem, but in the code above (i.e. the pagination parameters) there are typographical quotes, which won't work in real code. Replace them with regular quotes.

Comment: Wow I didn't see that you right ! I replaced them with regular quotes and now it's work perfectly thank you very much